# How to not have duplication between grails UrlMapping and angular Router

Tags: angularjs, grails, html5-history

I'm working on a grails/angular application, on which angular router is set to use HTML5 History. But, to use this setting we have to declare route in the angular router AND in the grails UrlMappings.

For instance, the angular router:

```
angular.module('myModule',['ngRoute']).config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 
   function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
      $routeProvider.when('my/url', {})
                    .when('my/other/url', {}) 
   }
]);
```

And the UrlMappings.groovy file :

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        //Here, duplication from the angular router
        //My Single Page Angular Application is on view index 
        'my/url'(view:'/index')
        'my/other/url'(view:'/index')
    }
}
```

has someone a clean solution to avoid the duplication between this 2 files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails apps provide a Spring bean named `grailsUrlMappingsHolder` that gives programmatic access to the URL mappings defined in the application (and it's plugins). This bean is an instance of [UrlMappingsHolder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/UrlMappingsHolder.html). You can read the URL mappings from the bean's `getUrlMappings()` method and construct the URLs in your angular router from this list.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's not perfect (lots of glue code to write for this to work as I want), but it will do for the time being

Comment: @Donal could you give an example with code please ?